# How to deal with a Zombie Pigmen army?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I safely survive the onslaught of this huge singular of zombie pigmen?

[image: Zombie pigmen army]

Comment: I assume you wanted to save that notch apple on your bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the best solution is to pillar-jump three blocks high:
[image: Pillar]

And cut them down, for you can attack at greater range than Zombie Pigmen can.

Answer (score 3):

Another way you could accomplish this is by digging a 4 block hole.[image]  Zombie Pigman wont jump more than 3 blocks down, and here you can still kit them while safe in the hole.

Comment: Need to take care that that none drop down as your digging the hole though, or push eachother in.

Comment: Also, the ground might very well not be four blocks deep...

Comment: Yeah, some down sides to digging the hole

Answer (score 0):

Just run away and don't attack any: attacking them cause the ones in a 32-block radius to get angry. Run until they stop attacking you (about 40 blocks).